# C - Want to put functions of type struct in separate .c-file

Tags: c, function, struct, header

So I have this code with a struct and a bunch of functions, and I want to put those functions (at least) in a separate .c-file. However, when I do, it no longer recognizes the struct card type that I have. What do I do?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct card {
    int suit;
    int value;
};

const char *suitName( int suitNum)
{
    switch (suitNum) {
    case 1: return "spades";
    case 2: return "clubs";
    case 3: return "hearts";
    case 4: return "diamonds";
    }

    return "(invalid suit)";
}

struct card makeCard(int suit, int value) {

    struct card tempCard;
    tempCard.suit = suit;
    tempCard.value = value;

    return tempCard;
}

struct card *createDeck()
{
    const size_t  count = 52;
    struct card *deck;


    /* Allocate new deck of 'count' cards. */
    deck = malloc(count * sizeof deck[0]);
    if (!deck) {
        fprintf(stderr, "createDeck(): Out of memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int i = 0;
    struct card *deckArrayPtr = deck;
    for (int suit = 1; suit < 5; suit++)
    {
        {
            for (int value = 1; value < 14; value++) {
                deck[i] = makeCard(suit, value);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

void shuffleDeck(struct card *deck) {
    int cardSwitch1, cardSwitch2;
    struct card temp;
    cardSwitch1 = (rand() % 52);
    cardSwitch2 = (rand() % 52);
    temp = deck[cardSwitch1];
    deck[cardSwitch1] = deck[cardSwitch2];
    deck[cardSwitch2] = temp;
}


int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); //initializing srand

    struct card *deckAr = createDeck(); //creating the struct card deck array

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        shuffleDeck(deckAr);
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < 52; a++) {
        //printf("%d of %s\n", deckAr[a].value, suitName(deckAr[a].suit));
        printf("%d of %s\n", deckAr[a].value, suitName(deckAr[a].suit));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a header file where you declerate your types and function prototypes

mytypes.h

```
struct card {
    int suit;
    int value;
};

const char *suitName( int suitNum);
struct card makeCard(int suit, int value);
...
```

Write a .c file where you implement your functions (include your header file)

myfunc.c

```
#include "mytypes.h"

const char *suitName( int suitNum)
{
    ...
}
...
```

Finally the file for your main program

main.c

```
#include "mytypes.h"

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought i somehow needed to prototype the struct but couldn't find anything online about it. Maybe should've figured it out on my own. ^^'